# Troubleshoot to create MYSQL view

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql so maybe to some of you my question will seem naive.

I have this query to create a table in database(here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b773d9)):

```
CREATE TABLE `hydrants log` (
  `TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TRIG` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

also I have this query to create view:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`geo`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `hydrants_log_maxtime` 
AS select `hydrants log`.`ID` AS `id`,`hydrants log`.`TRIG` AS `trig`,`hydrants log`.`VALUE` AS `value`,max(`hydrants log`.`TIME`) AS `time` from `hydrants log` group by `hydrants log`.`ID`;
```

When I try to create it in sql fiddle. I get this error:

```
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.
```

I guess the problem with this row:

```
UNDEFINED DEFINER=`geo`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `hydrants_log_maxtime`
```

So my question is how can I change the view query to create the view above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, problem is in `` DEFINER=`geo`@`%` `` parameter of view. There is no such user in MySQL database of sqlfiddle and you cannot assign him as view definer. All other parameters must work.
Also restriction like `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` will not work in sqlfiddle since you have only one user and cannot add new or edit existing. Query with this parameter will work, but it will be unused.

Comment: Andrew, do I only have to remove this DEFINER=geo@%`` from query?